# Adding Sourcegear Vault support

Tags: delphi, version-control, delphi-xe, sourcegear-vault

Simple. I use [Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) to manage my personal source files. But I don't like to check in/out outside the Delphi IDE.
Delphi XE supports Subversion so I wondered... Could I also get Vault to work with this? If not, are there alternative add-ins for Delphi **for free** available?
At work, I use a [commercial product](http://www.epocalipse.com/scx.htm) as Vault add-in. This is not an option for my work at home, which are just hobby-projects... Vault is also supported by Visual Studio so with Prism, it works. But the Delphi IDE doesn't.
Btw, Sourcegear Vault is [free for single-user environments](http://www.sourcegear.com/company/faq.html#singleuserpresent.). To quote:

> Somebody said that Vault is FREE for a single user. Is this true?
>  
>   Yes. Vault is free for use by a single user. Simply install the product and
>   do not enter any serial numbers at all. When no serial numbers are
>   present, Vault behaves as if there is exactly one user license. Note that
>   this free license does not apply when the product is used by more than one
>   person. If you have two people who need to use Vault, you will need to
>   purchase two initial licenses. If you enter a serial number containing only
>   one license, then the product will still have exactly one license
>   present.
>   And to be honest, it works very fine in my own single-user environment. :-)

Comment: I see that you alredy use SouceConnexion at work. I do not understand why you use Vault at home (AFAIK there is not a free version) yet don't want to use the same SCC plugin which is not expensive and look specifically for a free one. Othewise why not use SVN at home, for whcih you have alredy a Delphi plug-in?

Comment: For single-user setups, vault is free. :-)

Comment: It doesn't look so in its site... I can only found trial downloads

Comment: See the original post again. The quote there comes literally from the SourceGear site! Link: http://www.sourcegear.com/company/faq.html#singleuserpresent.

Comment: Ah, now I found it... pretty hidden in the FAQs. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Available options:

1. You use and modify the SVN
   integration code you can find on
   SourceForge (although IMHO it's not
   a good implementation, especially
   the menu layout).
2. You write a whole integration on your own using the OpenTool API (it could be a bit complex if you never worked with it)
3. If Vault supports the MS SCC interface (it should, if it works in VS), you can buy a plug in like [SourceConnexion](http://www.epocalipse.com/scx.htm) that adds SCC support to Delphi. Don't know if there is a version for XE already

Comment: Option 1, not so good. The SVN integration isn't really pretty. Option 2, a lot of work. I'm just hoping someone already did this. Option 3 is the solution from my question, but I don't want to rely on commercial plug-ins, especially since I'm just hobbying at home, using it all mostly for educational purposes and self-training.

Comment: Option 3 has the advantage of being a generic SCC integration, it would work with any VCS client supporting SCC. I do not know how much Vault is used among Delphi programmers, but Delphi lacks integrations for very common VCS as well. Anyway option 1 and 2 would be a good self-training for education purposes - to get something for free someone should write it first, and we can't always expect it would be someone else ;)

Comment: True. :-) Maybe I should write my own Vault Add-in for Delphi and make it free. I just hate the fact that I also use Visual Studio 2008 and 2010, plus Altova's MissionKit and these products have great support for Vault and other VCS systems built-in. Which my both my employer and myself like it. My employer was willing to buy SourceConnexion, though. Unfortunately, Delphi XE is not supported and it costs $59 more than I'm willing to spent on something I would only need with Delphi.

Comment: MS developed their SCC API years ago and it became a de-facto standard, and many VCS clients supports it. VS has no "built-in support" for them, is the other way round, those tools support the VS SCC API. AFAIK for license reasons Delphi never implemented it (don't know if license changes in the past would allow it, though). Nor BorCodeDero developed a simple API to allow integration without a deep knowledge of the little documentend OpenTools API. That's why I sometimes wonder if Delphi is a real "enterprise" development tool, as long as some useful pieces are missing.